# what is the meaning of 'along' here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

https://www.getyarn.io/yarn-clip/c3ed657b-b4cf-4206-a046-d8dcc3bac137

Hagrid says 
'but you're **a bit more along** than I would've expected. particularly here in the middle.'

but what's the meaning of 'along' there?
and isn't 'along' a preposition or an adverb, which cannot be followed by more..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**along** is used here to mean *bigger or grown up*. When Hagrid sees Dudley for the first time, he confuses him for Harry. The dialogue is as follows:

> Hagrid: Dry up, Dursley, you great prune. {The gun fires}
>
> All: Ahh!
>
> Hagrid: {sees Dudley} Mind, I haven't seen you since you was a baby,
>   Harry, but you're a bit more along than I would have expected.
>   Particularly 'round the middle!
>
> Dudley: I-I-I'm not Harry.
>
> Harry appears: I-I am.

Dudley is a somewhat overweight character in the movie - when Hagrid seems him and mistakenly believes him to be Harry, he says that Harry is bigger (more grown up) than he expected, particularly around the gut (he is also fatter than expected).